# ¿Cómo hacer Web scraping de una tabla?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, vb

estoy intentando traer una tabla de la siguiente página a Excel: https://bscscan.com/address/0x589ae3638468e122DcED9c836e03be82b97b3bcA

para ello estoy utilizando el siguiente código en VBA:

```
Sub TransaccionesBscscan()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
    
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "https://bscscan.com/address/0x589ae3638468e122dced9c836e03be82b97b3bca"
 
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.Document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
            .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
            .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
            .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(7).textContent
            .Range("I" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(8).textContent
            
        End With
        
        i = i + 1
    Next htmlEle    
End Sub
```

---

El inconveniente es que hay un problema cuando me trae los encabezados porque trae varios nombres de columna en algunas celdas y los agrupa juntos. y además no trae la última columna.
Dejo imágenes para que se entienda.

Tabla a traer con 8 columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo que pude obtener hasta el momento. Tiene mal los encabezados y no se como traer la última columna...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me da una mano le voy a estar muy agradecido!!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Utilizas la función Replace para reemplazar las palabras: from, to, filter y clear en la primera fila.
2. Te saltas la primera fila (cabecera) y escribes a mano los títulos tú mismo.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo del segundo caso:

```
Sub TransaccionesBscscan()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
    
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "https://bscscan.com/address/0x589ae3638468e122dced9c836e03be82b97b3bca"
 
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    
    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.Document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")

        If i = 1 Then
        
            
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("A" & i).Value = ""
                .Range("B" & i).Value = "Txn Hash"
                .Range("C" & i).Value = "Block"
                .Range("D" & i).Value = "Date"
                .Range("E" & i).Value = "Age"
                .Range("F" & i).Value = "From"
                .Range("G" & i).Value = ""
                .Range("H" & i).Value = "To"
                .Range("I" & i).Value = "Value"
                .Range("J" & i).Value = "Txn Fee"
            End With
            i = i + 1
        
        Else
        
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
                .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
                .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
                .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
                .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
                .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
                .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
                .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(7).textContent
                .Range("I" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(8).textContent
                .Range("J" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(9).textContent
                
            End With
            
            i = i + 1
            
        
        End If

    Next htmlEle
End Sub
```

Así te saltas el primer elemento (htmlEle) y escribes a mano los titulos. Que, por cierto, te faltaba por añadir una columna más.

Un saludo.